# Importing JavascriptExecutor (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, import, web-scraping

I might be missing something, but in every example I've inspected, JavascriptExecutor interface was imported simply by adding

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem to work for me. When I try that, I receive this error:

```
ImportError: No module named org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I'd be profoundly thankful.

Answer (score 6):

This is a Java import, not Python. Any way, you don't need any import as the `WebDriver` has built in function to run JavaScript

```
driver.execute_script('script')
```

Comment: Awesome!  I have read so many posts about different ways to import JavascriptExecutor, none of which worked as the OP said.  And all along it wasn't even necessary...  Probably why it can't be loaded anymore, it is built in.

Answer (score -1):

The error says it all :

```
ImportError: No module named org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

Which essentially means the module `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor` wasn't found in it's intended location.

### Reason

The issue can arise if the *Selenium Client* encounters an error while transmission or storage.

*Selenium Team* is currently working on the issue [*SeleniumHQ/selenium/5378*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5378) to generate the binary checksum of the *Downloaded Selenium Client* which will help you to avoid encountering errors which may have been introduced during its transmission or storage.

### Solution

Till then a solution will be to :

- Remove the references of the error-prone *JARs* from your *Project*.
- Clean the *Project Workspace* from your *IDE* & *Rebuild All*.
- Download a frest set of *JARs* from [*Selenium Release Storage*](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- If your *Web Browser* (i.e. Chrome/Firefox/IE) base version is too old, uninstall the *Web Browser* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA Release version of *Web Browser*.
- Add the required *JARs* only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your *Tests*.