# wont let me click with selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The first click command works but the second one returns

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1435, 1069)
```

I have tried setting sleeps up to 10 seconds but it won't work, so I do not think that the solution is that. The other solutions I find online either don't work or bring me to this same result.
What I am trying to do is click add to cart (Aggiungi a carrello) after selecting a shoe size.

```
 driver.get('https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/overbreak-bright-crimson')
 instock = (" ")
 elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ncss-btn-primary-dark.btn-lg")
 for el in elems:
    print(el.text)
    instock = el.text



if instock == ("Aggiungi Al Carrello"):
    print("ITS IN STOCK")

   
time.sleep(2)
size = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/button')
for si in size:
    print(si.text)
    fortyone = si.text
    si.click();
time.sleep(4)



elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ncss-btn-primary-dark.btn-lg")
for el in elems:
    print(el.text)
    el.click();
```

Comment: The 2nd locator is taking anything with a certain style set.   You should find a locator that's more targeted.  You should also avoid absolute path based locators.  (and won't need a loop for that 1st one as it's targeting a single button)

Comment: Are you at maximize window? because according to the numbers it looks like that the focus is not on the element, so one option is to scroll into it and other option that its not maximize

Comment: I have seen buttons which are actually not clickable in the center, which is where Selenium will click it.  If you continue to see this exception, use Actions chain to offset the click a little bit.  (You can test this manually by clicking exactly in the center to see if it works.)

Comment: nuzooo's onto something there... those coords look kinda odd.   You may want to add webdriverwaits here too.  Check for expected condition of toBeClickable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the element you are trying to click is out of the visible screen.
If so, you first need to scroll that element into view and only after that click it.
Scrolling the element into view can be done with the following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Webelement);
```

where `Webelement` is an element you are trying to scroll into the view

Comment: the click() method will automatically scroll the item into view.

Comment: @pcalkins No, it never does this. You are wrong.

Comment: Well, I see, but..  I have some real experience writing some Selenium code for the last 6-7 years. So, what I see in practice - Selenium `.click()` method simulates exactly the click as it was done by user on GUI. Exactly the click, not scrolling or any other additional action. Additionally, you google for ` Element is not clickable at point` and will see that this can be caused by several things and in this case - since adding a sleep doesn't help and the height is more than regular screen height - (1435, 1069) - I guess the problem is with scrolling that is, again, should be done explicitly

Comment: js scroll is sometimes necessary for dynamically loading components or when an overlayed object is intercepting.

Comment: OK, let's ask the topic starter whether my answer worked for him

Comment: Does this work in python? I try to import it and use it to no avail

Comment: Sure, it should. This is a JavaScript, it should work with any other language. Just put the element you wish to scroll to, in your case `el` instead of the `Webelement` there

Comment: No, im saying that importing the executor isn't working. I think that it is because I'm using python. The import code I tried is 'import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor' but that does not work

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857871/importing-javascriptexecutor-selenium you don't need to import JavascriptExecutor, it's part of the driver

Comment: ok thx, it centers it on the page... I ended up using 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", el);

It stopped clicking anything (even the first part) but that's probably an easy fix.

Comment: So, I understand we resolved your problem?